# Can I use two controllers in the same diretive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a partial view which uses a controller (e.g. ctrl1), but in that partial view I have also a directive with its own templateURL and I want to move the specific logic from ctrl1 to the directive's controller but keeping some constants or common logic (for other directives) in ctrl1.

Is this possible?

An approximate approach very summed up:

ctrl1:
-a
-b
-c

ctrl1 -> ctrl2:

ctrl1:
-a

ctrl2:
-b
-c

With an example in detail:

ctrl1:

```
var ctrl1 = angular.module("MyModule1", []);
ctrl1.controller("MyCtrl1", function($scope){
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.test = function(){
    //whatever
  };
  $scope.secondtest = function(){
    //whatever again
  };
});
```

And after moving some logic to ctrl2 (directive's controller), the controllers are:

ctrl1:

```
var ctrl1 = angular.module("MyModule1", []);
ctrl1.controller("MyCtrl1", function($scope){
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.test = function(){
    //whatever
  };
});
```

directive:

```
var direc = angular.module("MyModule2", []);
direc.directive("MyDirective", function(){
  return{
     controller: function($scope){  //This is what I called ctrl2 previously
       $scope.secondtest = function(){
         //whatever again
       };
     },
     templateURL: 'partials/dialog/userdata.html'
  }
 });
```

And in the directive I still want to use the function "$scope.test", or "$scope.a" variable and the second test function have access to that data, maybe it has to query the value of "$scope.a"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is indeed very summed up.

Comment: Do you want to move the logic to the directive or rather make it *accessible* in your directive?

Comment: I will extend the explanation, this is just for having an overview :)

Comment: @Sprottenwels I want to move just part of the logic from controller to directive, but still using common elements from the original controller.

Comment: I'll wait for the extended explanation

Comment: @Sprottenwels explanation added

Comment: @arturgrzesiak explanation updated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need is to access to the parent scope. You can use $scope.$parent from the child controller.

Anyways, as you say you want common logic or constants, it sounds you need to use a service (singleton) that can be accessed from every controller.

EDITED: After seeing your code, in this case the directive is using the same scope that the enclosing controller so things as $scope.test() or $scope.a should work from the directive.

Comment: It's not exactly that, because now If I leave the controller for the partial view, the directives works fine with that controller, but that controller is messy, so I want to move the specific login for each directive to its directive's controller, and just keep in ctrl1 the common variables or common function used by all the directives.